# Tabela não sobrepondo valores

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Estou recebendo dados do banco de dados firebase e preenchendo em uma tabela dinamicamente. Quando chega novas informações a tabela não sobrepõe os dados, ela repete as linhas e coloca a novo dado embaixo sem apagar as anteriores. Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código html:

```
<table class="table" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nível de Urgência</th>
      <th>Tipo de serviço</th>
      <th>Mensagem</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tabelaOcorrencias">

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    inicializa();
}

function inicializa() {
    database.ref('ocorrencias').on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(item) {
          item.forEach(function(cont) {
            InsertDataTable(cont.val(), cont.key, item.key);
          })
        })
      });
}

function InsertDataTable(fila, idOcorrencia, idUsuario) {
   var tbodyTable = document.getElementById('tabelaOcorrencias');
   var tbody = tbodyTable.insertRow(fila.length);

   tbody.innerHTML = '';
   tbody.innerHTML += `
     <td>${idOcorrencia}</td><td>${fila.nivelUrgencia}</td>
     <td>${fila.tipoServiço}</td><td>${fila.mensagem}</td>
     <td>${fila.status}</td>
     <button type="submit" onclick="alterarOcorrencia('${idOcorrencia}', 
     '${idUsuario}')" class="btn btn-danger">Atender</button>
    `

}
```

Como faço para apagar antes de inserir?

Comment: Depende, como você chama a função `InsertDataTable`?

Comment: Editei o código